# Можно ли сказать "прилежно сдал экзамен"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если посмотреть на значение слова "прилежно" и на его ближайшие синонимы, мы увидим слова "усердно" и "старательно". Но ведь нельзя сдать экзамен усердно? Его можно сдать только хорошо или плохо ну или успешно.

Comment: Ну, все правильно. Сами же и ответили. ))

Answer (score 1):

Правильность употребления слова желательно проверять по словарю, а не по синонимам (не все синонимы одинаково хороши для проверки).

ПРИЛЕЖНЫЙ, Усердный, старательный. П. ученик. П. работник. Прилежен в изучении истории. <Прилежно, нареч. П. учиться, учить уроки.

Сказать "он прилежно сдал экзамен", на первый взгляд, сложно, но вот "прилежно сдавать экзамены" уже, пожалуй, можно. Это будет означать, что вы  не прогуливаете экзамены и тщательно к ним готовитесь.

С другой стороны,  "он прилежно сдал экзамен" также может означать хорошую подготовку к одному экзамену. Правда, фраза кажется немного архаичной.

Comment: Вот я сижу - и полдня уже именно над этим думаю: можно перенести "прилежно" именно на подготовку к экзамену. Очень хочется, а не получается. У вас есть какая-нибудь аргументация в пользу того, что можно - ну хотя бы на примерах-аналогах?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению, надо будет тоже поискать примеры. Сейчас так, скорее всего,  не говорят, но, возможно, говорили раньше.

Answer (score 0):

Так говорить не надо! ***Прилежно*** можно что-то делать в течение длительного времени, нужен глагол несовершенного вида, ср.: ***прилежно заниматься, учиться***. А ***сдать*** - глагол совершенного вида, означающий кратковременное действие.